# Transform from ios6 to ios7

Tags: ipad, ios7

I have an universal app where I successfully upgraded the iPhone component to ios7.
The ipad component however is not running anymore. I get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISplitViewController tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d9eef0'

I have no idea what happened. I did not touch the ipad side of things whatsoever.

I am running: 11A4449d build and 5A11365y build for x-code on a mac machine.

After this code the error happens:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // whenever I come out of a storyboard, I make myself the delegate of any splitview I am in
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: The error clearly says you are sending a message to an object that doesn't respond to that message.  The snippet of code you've provided doesn't help us to know what.  You'll just need to step through this in the debugger to find out where the view controller hierarchy is different to what you expect.

Comment: I went through my code again. Had a breakpoint at the line:- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions and realised that I added some code to modify the TabBarItems for the iPhone. Clearly the iPad did not like that so I put this line of code around it:   BOOL piPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    if (!piPad)
    { <CODE THAT CAUSED THE PROBLEM FOR iPAD> ). That solved it.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to sort out your own problem.

Comment: @user2713097: please post your solution as an answer and accept, so others going through the question list can see that it's no longer open.

Answer (score 0):

In this method: I set the selected image on a tab bar for the iPhone.
But did not realise that the iPad will not like it. So I put a selective statement (if !iPad) around it to fix it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    BOOL piPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    if (!piPad)
    {

        // **************************************************************************************************
        // Assign tab bar item with titles and selected images
        UITabBarController *pTabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

        UITabBar *pTabBar = pTabBarController.tabBar;
        UITabBarItem *pTabBarItem0 = [pTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];


        pTabBarItem0.title = @"List";


        pTabBarItem0.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarList_30x30_selected"];
        pTabBarItem0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarList_30x30.png"];


        // **************************************************************************************************
    }

    return YES;
```